# How to configure SSL on localhost with self signed certificate on IIS?

Tags: ssl, iis, localhost

I'm pretty new dealing with IIS, so forgive me if i misunderstand something here and for my amateurism. I created here a self signed certificate for a site, on the creation a i need to put "*.site " as a friendly name ? That friendly name needs to match the domain name to the site ? Than i proceed to bind the certificate to the site, i selected the protocol https, put the host name, the IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, the port (3000), select the certificate than clicked OK,

[Edit site binding screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M97wq.png)

I open the browser, the certificate is vinculated to the site, and the URL stays like : "https: //site.com:3000". But the site comes with a UNSECURE status.

That's running on localhost.

I'm getting those 2 errors here, first one (SAN) is related to a package missing on the certificate with an alternative subject name. I cannot add that property on a self signed certificate, right ?
And the second one is related to "common name invalid" that i have no idea why that happening.

I need a north to solve this. 
Thanks in advance.

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72oqv.png)

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/self-signed.html#self-signed-certificate-wizard Friendly name is useless here. You need to set a valid DNS name to match the domain name to access to the site. The "Unsecure" status can come due to more factors, and SSL Diag can tell you some, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

SSL/TLS can be quite of a challenging topic for a non-security expert, however by understanding how the protocol works most of your questions will be answered. I would not recommend to focus on the IIS specifics, and rather study [the core of SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818).

Another great technical resource is the [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280), that proposes a standard for Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure Certificate and Certificate Revocation List (CRL) Profile.

One thing to keep in mind is: **Browsers do not like self-signed server certificates**. Whenever using it, a lot of warnings will be issued. The most common ones being (warning message may vary depending on version):

1. The SSL certificate is not issued by a Trusted CA (Certificate Authority) or a self-signed certificate is used to secure the website.

> Self explanatory warning message.

2. [Error:net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4981025180483584)

> "[RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818) describes two methods to match a domain name against a certificate - using the available names within the subjectAlternativeName extension, or, in the absence of a SAN extension, falling back to the commonName. The fallback to the commonName was deprecated in RFC 2818 (published in 2000), but support still remains in a number of TLS clients, often incorrectly."

The second one answer most of your questions regarding how to correctly issue a self-signed certificate for your server.

Cheers.